# backbone.js collection from json file into a template

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, collections, underscore.js

I have been through a number of questions already in regard to this. Some older questions with old methods do not work with the latest versions of _.js and backbone.js and I am a bit lost to tell you the truth as well.

Learning backbone.js at the moment, going well, going back to good habits with MVC etc which is great. Got lazy a bit with jQuery.

Anyway...
I been through a few things and this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bBtgt/1/

```
var postsObject = [{
    "_id": "50f5f5d4014e045f000002",
        "author": {
        "name": "Chris Crawford",
        "photo": "http://example.com/photo.jpg"
    },
        "status": "This is a sample message.",
        "comments": [{
        "_id": "5160eacbe4b020ec56a46844",
            "text": "This is the content of the comment.",
            "author": "Bob Hope"
    }, {
        "_id": "5160eacbe4b020ec56a46845",
            "text": "This is the content of the comment.",
            "author": "Bob Hope"
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "50f5f5d4014e045f000003",
        "author": {
        "name": "Brown Robert",
            "photo": "http://example.com/photo.jpg"
    },
        "status": "This is another sample message.",
        "comments": [{
        "_id": "5160eacbe4b020ec56a46846",
            "text": "This is the content of the comment.",
            "author": "Bob Hope"
    }, {
        "_id": "5160eacbe4b020ec56a46847",
            "text": "This is the content of the comment.",
            "author": "Bob Hope"
    }]
}];

// Comment Model
var Comment = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: '_id',
    defaults: {
        text: "",
        author: ""
    }
});

// Comments collection
var Comments = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Comment
});

// Author Model
var Author = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        text: "",
        author: ""
    }
});

// Post Model
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: '_id',
    defaults: {
        author: "",
        status: ""
    },
    parse: function (resp) {
        // Create a Author model on the Post Model
        this.author = new Author(resp.author || null, {
            parse: true
        });
        // Delete from the response object as the data is
        // alredy available on the  model
        delete resp.author;
        // Create a comments objecton model 
        // that will hold the comments collection
        this.comments = new Comments(resp.comments || null, {
            parse: true
        });
        // Delete from the response object as the data is
        // alredy available on the  model
        delete resp.comments;

        // return the response object 
        return resp;
    }
})
// Posts Collection 
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post
});

var PostsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#container",
    renderPostView: function(post) {
        // Create a new postView
        var postView = new PostView({
            model : post
        });
        // Append it to the container
        this.$el.append(postView.el);
        postView.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var thisView = this;
        // Iterate over each post Model
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (post) {
            // Call the renderPostView method
            thisView.renderPostView(post);
        });
    }
});


var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "post",
    template: _.template($("#post-template").html()),
    renderComments: function() {
        var commentsListView = new CommentsListView({
            // Comments collection on the Post Model
            collection : this.model.comments,
            // Pass the container to which it is to be appended
            el : $('.comments', this.$el)
        });
        commentsListView.render();        
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.empty();
        //  Extend the object toi contain both Post attributes
        // and also the author attributes
        this.$el.append(this.template(_.extend(this.model.toJSON(),
            this.model.author.toJSON()
       )));
       // Render the comments for each Post
       this.renderComments();
    }
});

var CommentsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    renderCommentView: function(comment) {
        // Create a new CommentView
        var commentView = new CommentView({
            model : comment
        });
        // Append it to the comments ul that is part
        // of the view
        this.$el.append(commentView.el);
        commentView.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var thisView = this;
        // Iterate over each Comment Model
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (comment) {
            // Call the renderCommentView method
            thisView.renderCommentView(comment);
        });
    }
});


var CommentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    className: "comment",
    template: _.template($("#comment-template").html()),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});

// Create a posts collection 
var posts = new Posts(postsObject, {parse: true});

// Pass it to the PostsListView
var postsListView = new PostsListView({
    collection: posts
});
// Render the view
postsListView.render();
```

Has a great use of multiple collections reading from a JSON object.

What I have though is a JSON FILE which I will need to read from and also eventually write to, to update.

Could someone, through the fiddle help me understand how to change this from reading from an inline JSON object in the collection to having the collection read from a JSON file of data instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

General example using jQuery's ajax methods and PHP:

Client side:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/document.json", function (data) {
  data.someProperty = "new value";
  saveFile(data);
});

function saveFile(json) {
  $.post("http://www.example.com/save-file-api.php", {data: json}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Server side (save-file-api.php):

```
<?php
  if ($_POST["data"]) {
     if (file_put_contents("/document.json", $_POST["data"]) !== false) {
       echo "File saved successfully.";
     } else {
       echo "Error while saving file.";
     }
  }
```

This could be done many ways. Basically, request your JSON document, fiddle around with it, then send it back to your server, which will save it.

Backbone also has [an API for this](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync), you may want to look into it but apparently they use jQuery behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi Jackson, thanks but that is not what I was looking for. I know how to write to the file in the scope of what I am doing (not PHP) and read using jQuery.
I am after how to get JSON from a file into a backbone.js collection and output via a view in the template.Rather then an inline object.

Comment: Check out `Collection.url`, `Collection.fetch()` and `Collection.sync()`. Those look promising.